# Getting value from SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to get a saved value from an activity by this `Settings.getMode();` Here is the `Settings` class :

```
public class Set extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

private static String isNightMode;
Switch aSwitch;
Boolean mode;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("xyz", MODE_PRIVATE);
    isNightMode = sharedPreferences.getString("isNightMode", "no");
    mode = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("mode", false);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set);

    aSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    aSwitch.setChecked(mode);

    if (aSwitch.isChecked()) {
        isNightMode = "yes";
    } else {
        isNightMode = "no";
    }

    aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}

public static String getMode() {
    return isNightMode;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        isNightMode = "yes";
        mode = true;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("isNightMode", isNightMode);
        editor.putBoolean("mode", mode);
        editor.commit();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        isNightMode = "no";
        mode = false;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("isNightMode", isNightMode);
        editor.putBoolean("mode", mode);
        editor.commit();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

When I change the value in `Settings` activity , the value is saved perfectly. But problem is , I am not getting the saved value when the app starts . When the app starts, the `getMode()` method returns null. There must be something wrong while getting saved value at the time of starting the app. I can't figure out the wrong.

Comment: First of all, try to put `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in your first line of `onCreate` method.
And it would be great if you post your error log as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Comment: @MohammadZarei, Actually there is no error . Problem is I am not getting the saved mode (day/night mode) when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

**1.you can use it `MyApplication`  .**

**2.and call `MyApplication.getMode();` in your Activity .**

Try this .

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static String isNightMode;
Boolean mode;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("xyz", MODE_PRIVATE);
    isNightMode = sharedPreferences.getString("isNightMode", "no");
    mode = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("mode", false);
}

public static String getMode() {
    return isNightMode;
}

}
```

And add in the `manifest`

```
<application
    android:name=".yourPackage.MyApplication"
    ...                             />
```

Comment: No change. Not getting the saved mode(night/day mode) on app start.

Answer (score 0):

This modification might help you. Modification in onCreate() method:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); // this - Activity
```

and

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit(); // this - Activity

    if (isChecked) {
        isNightMode = "yes";
        mode = true;                       

    } else {
        isNightMode = "no";
        mode = false;
    }

    editor.putString("isNightMode", isNightMode);
    editor.putBoolean("mode", mode);
    editor.apply();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Tried. But no change.